# Visual Studio Code Pylint AutoFix Not Showing Up On Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, pylint

I set up a python project in visual studio code and this is the debugging option I'm using in my `launch.json`:

```
  {
            "name": "External Terminal/Console",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "",
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit"
            ]
        }
```

I installed `pylint` and created a `settings.json` file which looks exactly like this:

```
{
 "python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
 "python.linting.pep8Path": "/usr/bin/pep8",
 "python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/bin/pylint"
}
```

The `pylint` linter errors are being displayed but there is no lightbubble showing up which helps fixing linter errors automatically.

What is causing this and how can I enable the `lightbubble` which helps me to fix the linter errors e.g. `Fix all autofixable errors`.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no lightbubble from Pylint.

If you need a linter with lightbubble, try [SonarLint](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/sonarlint/).